# Open Camera Button is saved in the final png screenshot

Tags: java, android, android-camera-intent

I created an app to take photos using mobile's camera, show GPS coordinates as a text, and save the image to mobile's gallery. The problem is that the final screenshot saved in mobile's picture gallery contains the "Open Camera" BUTTON. How can I remove it from the screenshot (png) saved?

[image]

This is my code:

```
       /* capture image */

         private void captureImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    File photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    String authorities = getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider";
    Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, authorities, photoFile);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);

}

/* create image file to store photo */
  String mCurrentPhotoPath;
   private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );         // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Where to add the openCameraButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);   and openCameraButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); ? Is there any way to NOT store my image to the mobile's default pictures directory after taking photo ?

Comment: The open camera button is always visible in app's screen for user to be able to capture photos. When foto is captured via camera, the app returns the foto taken by the user and displays coordinates,date,time. Then I take a snapshot of the app's screen and save it to mobile's picture gallery (images displayed above). How can programmatically remove the open camera button at the bottom?

Comment: share your code

Comment: Code is shared above. Thanks

Comment: the shared code shows only how you create your intent for starting the camera.. for others to helps they needs to understand when/how you launch those intents and what you in your onactivityresult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the description and the photo you've attached, we can assume that this button opens the phone's camera and (probably) takes a picture. If that's true, you can hide the visibility of the button before the screenshot is taken with `openCameraButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);` and show the button again, once you've taken the screenshot: `openCameraButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: The openCameraButton.setVisibility(View.GONE); and openCameraButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); was the solution to my issue.